# Django variable substituted in template directly but not in custom tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-custom-tags

I created a custom tag, that works similarly to a block tag:

```
@register.tag
def dash(parser, token):
    nodelist = parser.parse(('enddash',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    args = token.split_contents()

    title = args[1]

    return DashNode(nodelist, title)


class DashNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, nodelist, title):
        self.nodelist = nodelist

        if title[0] in ('"', "'") and title[0] == title[-1]:
            self.title = title[1:-1]
        else:
            self.title = template.Variable(title)

        self.tpl = """
<div class="dashboard-body container-fluid main-section-body view-mode" data-role="main">
    <div class="dashboard-header clearfix">
        <h2>{title}</h2>
    </div>
{content}
</div>"""

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            title = self.title.resolve(context)
        except AttributeError:
            title = self.title

        output = self.nodelist.render(context)

        new_output = self.tpl.format(content=output, title=title)
        return new_output
```

The tag accepts an argument, that can be a string or a variable. I created it following [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag).

Tag works without problem with a string. If I use a variable:

```
{% dash page_title %}
   <!-- blablabla -->
{% enddash %}
```

a `VariableDoesNotExist` error is raised. But the variable is correctly expanded if I use it directly in the template.

I'm using Django 1.5.5 (and I'm locked with it...)

Answer (score 0):

VariableDoesNotExist is thrown in line `self.title.resolve(context)` because when instanitating `template.Variable(title)`, title does not correspond to an existing variable in the current `context`. That could mean that in your example `title` is not `"page_title"`. Check.

Comment: `title` is `page_title`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work now. I've not changed my code at all. Probably this is caused by the framework I'm using (Splunk).